# JavaScript | Waypoints plugin confilcting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

Hi I am using the JavaScript plugin for waypoints in my document. The issue I am having is that when I have one Waypoint it works and runs the correct function but as soon as I place another neither of them work.

[Waypoints Plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/)

below is the working one

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById('waypoint'),
    handler: function(direction){
        start();
        waypoint.destroy()
    }
});
```

When i add the second one like below neither of them work and i cannot figure out why

```
var waypoint2 = new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById('waypoint2'),
    handler: function(direction){
        alert('hello');
        waypoint2.destroy()
    }
});

var waypoint = new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById('waypoint'),
    handler: function(direction){
        start();
        waypoint.destroy()
    }
});
```

any ideas? Thanks, Kieran

Answer (score 0):

```
var waypoints = $('#waypoint').waypoint(function(){
    start();
});

var waypoints = $('#waypoint2').waypoint(function(){
    alert('test');
    waypoints.destroy();
});
```